# Nodered IBM-examples are not working on my PC

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I tried 2 example programs from the IBM website.

[timestamp example](http://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/first-flow)

I cannot see anything in the debug tab. Debug node is of course activated and its output is set to debug tab and console.

Chrome developer tools gives some more information:

> Warning: SVG's SMIL animations (, , etc.) are deprecated and will be removed. Please use CSS animations or Web animations instead.

It also detects that something has happended (Preview "OK", Response "OK").

I also tried [Chat example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-rtchat-app/)
But even when I try to execute the "Run the app" button the window never displays "connection established" or any chat message. Chrome developer tools throws error:

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.

I did not install anything related to Java, JS, JSON, Node.js on my pc as I asume that everything runs inside Bluemix.

Comment: If you've not installed anything on your PC, where exactly are you running Node-RED?

Comment: @knolleary Inside Bluemix as I've written. I just used a boilerplate (Node-RED starter community), started the application and did the steps from the  timestamp example instructions.

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed the Bluemix comment at the end. The SVG warning is unrelated to this, so you can ignore that.

Comment: I've just tried the timestamp example and it works fine for me in Bluemix. Can you try accessing the editor using https rather than http? That helps solve some websocket connectivity issues we see on certain networks.

Comment: Okay, debug messages are displayed with https.Thanks! However, is it normal that most of the time when trying to deploy in https an error appears (Error. {"error" : "Unexpected_error"})? After waiting a couple of seconds I can deploy (Successfully deployed). Oh and if you write an answer instead of a comment I can accept your answer I guess.

Comment: No, 'unexpected_error' is not normal... would be useful to see the logs which you can access via the app's dashboard in the bluemix console.

Comment: 2016-03-30T15:09:04.608+0200[App/0]OUT30 Mar 13:09:04 - [warn] Error saving flows: undefined
2016-03-30T15:09:04.609+0200[App/0]OUT30 Mar 13:09:04 - [warn] undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying issue is a failure to establish a websocket connection with the node-red instance running in Bluemix. This is a known issue when accessing from certain networks that is usually resolved by accessing the application using https rather than http.

Comment: Beside the frequently appearing unexpected errors with using debug-nodes the chat app is still not working (I can never see the [connected] on the https://appname.mybluemix.net/chat site).  Still the "still in CONNECTING state" error pointing to line ws.send(JSON.stringify(payload));

Comment: have you given up on me?:)

Comment: This isn't the best place to debug this. Suggest you contact the author of the chat example or take this to the Node-RED Mailing list - link at bottom of nodered.org